# How to change the color of the rectangle after every cycle count?

Tags: java, javafx, colors

I have a rectangle which animates from left to right. I want the rectangle to change color randomly after every cycle count, but I want it to change the color from the selected colors only. For instance, I have color red, blue and orange, then I want the rectangle to change the color from those red, blue and orange color only. For example, if it move from left to right then first it is blue, then after one cycle count (when it finishes from left to right) then it should change the color to red or orange and so on.

Here is my following code:

```
public class Rect extends Application {


@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Pane canvas = new Pane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(canvas, 500, 600);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle (100, 40, 100, 100);
    rect.setArcHeight(50);
    rect.setArcWidth(50);
    rect.setFill(Color.BLUE);

    TranslateTransition tt1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(3000), rect);
    tt1.setByY(1000f);
    tt1.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    tt1.setAutoReverse(false);
    tt1.play();
    canvas.getChildren().add(rect);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Timeline` instead of a `TranslateTransition`. A `Timeline` uses a collection of `KeyFrame`s, and a `KeyFrame` allows you to specify a handler to execute when the frame is reached, as well as a property and value for that property:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Rect extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Pane canvas = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(canvas, 500, 600);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 40, 100, 100);
        rect.setArcHeight(50);
        rect.setArcWidth(50);
        rect.setFill(Color.BLUE);

        Color[] palette = new Color[] { Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.ORANGE };
        Random rng = new Random();

        Timeline tt1 = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(
                Duration.millis(3000), 
                e -> rect.setFill(palette[rng.nextInt(palette.length)]), 
                new KeyValue(rect.yProperty(), 1040)
            )
        );

        tt1.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        tt1.setAutoReverse(false);
        tt1.play();
        canvas.getChildren().add(rect);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working, thanks. But can you explain me this line of code:  `e -> rect.setFill(palette[rng.nextInt(palette.length)]), 
                new KeyValue(rect.yProperty(), 1040)`

Comment: What's to explain? It is part of the call to the [`KeyFrame` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html#KeyFrame-javafx.util.Duration-javafx.event.EventHandler-javafx.animation.KeyValue...-). The parameter `e -> rect.setFill(...)` is the event handler that is invoked when the frame is reached, and the `KeyValue` is the key value for the frame.

Comment: I didn't get what does palette.length does and what is (rect.yProperty(), 1040). Can you please explain me. I am newbie, so I don't know much. It is appreciated.

Comment: `palette.length` is the length of the array `palette`. `(rect.yProperty(), 1040)` are the parameters provided to the [`KeyValue` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyValue.html#KeyValue-javafx.beans.value.WritableValue-T-). I can't give an entire Java tutorial in the comments to an answer on this forum.

Comment: I understand  the palette.length, but I still didn't understand (rect.yProperty(), 1040). Can you please turn this in chat, so you can explain me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151955/discussion-between-hemlata-and-james-d).

Comment: @Hemlata the timeline interpolates over the the properties represented by the key values every pulse (usually 60 times per second), varying the value of the property according to the chosen interpolator.  What `new KeyValue(rect.yProperty(), 1040)`  effectively means is that the value of the y property of the rectangle will be set to 1040 at the completion of the key frame.  In this case the keyframe has a duration of 3 seconds.  So over the 3 second duration, the rectangle moves from wherever it currently is to y value 1040 (just like a TranslateTransition toY setting).